# Converting string with am/pm in date

Tags: t-sql

I have a varchar field in where I have the following value:
03/09/2012 11:40:25 a.m.

I need to convert this string in datetime. When I try to apply CONVERT but I get error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: I just did declare @dt varchar(20) = '03/09/2012 11:40:25 a.m.'
                   select convert(datetime,@dt) with no error...what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the correct `DATEFORMAT` order its the period(s) that are causing the issue so;

```
convert(datetime, replace('03/09/2012 11:40:25 a.m.', '.', ''))
```